# How to define $E(X|\mathbb{1}_{A})$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $A$ an event (outcome), $P(A)>0$. How do we define $E(X|A)$ and $E(X|\mathbb{1}_{A})$?

I know that $E(X|A)=\frac{1}{P(A)}E(X\mathbb{1}_A)$, so this is covered.

But how is $E(X|\mathbb{1}_A)$ defined? It should look like this (or similar, if my memory serves me): $$E(X|A)P(\mathbb{1}_A)+E(X|A^c)P(\mathbb{1}_A).$$
Is this correct? And if so, why?

---

Also as a side question. What is or how do we define $P(\mathbb{1}_A)?$

This was a question on a theoretical test in our probability class.

Comment: I think this is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function?

Comment: I do know what an indicator function is and have already looked on wikipedia. But nowhere does it say what $E(X|\mathbb{1}_A)$ is.

Comment: It depends on the context a bit, but the most general situation identifies $E[X \mid Y]$ with $E[X \mid \sigma(Y)]$, where $\sigma(Y)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by the random variable $Y$. Thus it is also a random variable, but one completely determined by the value of $Y$. In the case $Y=1_A$ this is $E[X \mid A]$ if $A$ occurred and $E[X \mid A^c]$ if $A$ did not occur.

Comment: Looking at any proper definition of conditional expectation during one minute should suffice to convince you that $$E(X\mid\mathbb 1_A)=E(X\mid\mathbb 1_{A^c})=E(X\mid A)\mathbb 1_A+E(X\mid A^c)\mathbb 1_{A^c}$$

Comment: "What is or how do we define $P(\mathbb{1}_A)?$" DNE.

Comment: @Jack This is all the context we were given. It is from a theoretical test in our probability class.

Comment: @Did Thank you, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for an intuitive answer. Did not struck me to just look at the indicator as an ordinary random variable.

Comment: @Jack "I doubt that a one-line definition would be helpful to you." Doubting is allright in principle, but in the present case your doubt (which you do not care to explain) seems unfounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general manner to define conditional expectation is through the $\sigma$-algebra definition, in which $E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is the a.s.-unique random variable such that $E[X \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and $E[X 1_A]=E[E[X \mid \mathcal{G}] 1_A]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$. One can use this to define conditional expectation with respect to a random variable by identifying $E[X \mid Y]$ and $E[X \mid \sigma(Y)]$ where $\sigma(Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which $Y$ is measurable. In the case $Y=1_A$ this definition tells you

$$E[X \mid 1_A]=E[X \mid A] 1_A + E[X \mid A^c] 1_{A^c}.$$

Assuming $0<P(A)<1$, both of the expectations on the right side can be defined in the manner you mentioned. If either inequality fails then it becomes non-obvious how to define one of the terms, but in that situation the "bad" term can be simply ignored because it is only relevant with probability zero (and conditional expectation is only unique up to a null set).